# submitting data into mysql database using PHP as the process engine using javascript xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i am facing the problem here.. i wanna update the data from my multiple front-end forms which are contained student profile, parents profile, academic information and so on.. if i update these forms just using PHP without JavaScript, all my data in my tables can update properly but when i attached my JavaScript framework file, my data triggered the error's alert and its unable to update the mysql table. I only use native JavaScript and XMLHttpRequest (i believe it is one of AJAX syntax).. below is my syntax of JS.. thanks for help.. for this moment, i don't wanna use jQuery for this moment because i wanna deeply understand the JavaScript's flow first. thanks for help..

```
function checkStatus(){
    var icNumber = document.getElementById("studentICNumber").value;
    var studentName = document.getElementById("studentFullname").value;

    var no = document.getElementById("no");
    var yes = document.getElementById("yes");

    var updateDB = function(noic){
    var xmlhttp;
    //var noic;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "studentStatus.php?noic="+noic, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};

if(no.checked === true){
    alert(studentName + " is not eligible to enter this college");
    window.location="updateStudentStatus.php";
}
else{
    if(updateDB(icNumber)){
        alert("Done Updating The Information For " + studentName);
        //window.location.reload();
    }
    else{
        alert("There is an error.");
        //document.getElementById("messageAlert_1").innerHTML = "error";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Need more code (we can't tell what's going on from just this). What is invoking this file? Is this wrapped in another function?

Comment: it's invoking the error as i wrote as the alert.. and this code is not wrapping in another function.. only checkStatus() function.. before this i have separated the functions between checkStatus() - to check my student status and updateStudentStatus() - to update student status into my mysql..

Comment: Please do not edit in "Closed" into your question titles like that again.